# json decode/encode repeated array

Tags: php, json

hey ive managed to decode the encode json i created but when i try to print the decoded array it repeats the same username ( the last one on the list ) over and over again. what i want is that all the users are desplayed

this is the code for the encoded json array

```
$query = 
  "SELECT 
  userid, 
  username, 
  password, 
  email 
  FROM Users ORDER BY userid";

$results = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
```

The encoded array code below

```
<?php
echo "Data with Json Encoding";
foreach($results as $row){

    $encode = json_encode($row, true);
    echo '<pre>';print_r($encode); echo '</pre>';
    }
 ?>
```

the decoded array code below

```
<?php
    echo "Data with Json Decoding";
    foreach($results as $row){
    $decode = json_decode($encode, true);
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($decode);'</pre>';
   }
```

this is the result of the code Data with Json Decoding

```
Array
(
    [userid] => 239
    [username] => desposit4221
    [password] => 699e5fae54df4c82314e42dd86c4d383
    [email] => ad471993@hotmail.com
) 

Array
(
    [userid] => 239
    [username] => desposit4221
    [password] => 699e5fae54df4c82314e42dd86c4d383
    [email] => ad471993@hotmail.com
)
```

it's this over and over again, it should be the list of my users

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You are decoding `$encode`. `$encode` contains the last value you assigned to it, ie the last value encountered in the previous loop ("Data with Json Encoding"), ie the last row of your array. So each iteration you are decoding the same string.

Comment: Every time you loop, you are *resetting* `$encode` to the next value.  When the loop's done, `$encode` is set to the last element.

Comment: Explain why you need to encode and then re-decode your data so that we can give you a more appropriate solution. (Probably encoding your whole array and then decoding this string once, you don't need a loop.)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "Data with Json Encoding";
$encodedResults = array();
foreach($results as $row){

    $encode = json_encode($row, true);
    echo '<pre>';print_r($encode); echo '</pre>';

    $encodedResults[] = $encode;
}
 ?>
```

```php
echo "Data with Json Decoding";
foreach($encodedResults as $row){
    $decode = json_decode($row, true);
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($decode);'</pre>';
}
```

Comment: This solution works but I don't get why not encoding the whole array first. What is the point if after encoding we still have an array of encoded data, and not just an encoded string?

Comment: Thanks mate that worked . its uni work its not going into anything real i just have to show i have done both encoding and decoding

Answer (score 0):

If you put the line

```
$encode = json_encode($row, true);
```

into your second loop just after the `foreach` line, you should get the results you expect. It's a reasonable way to explore the datamanagement aspects of php. Good luck in your projects!

Answer (score 0):

Encode your array:

```
echo "Data with Json Encoding";
$encoded_datas = json_encode($results);
echo $encoded_datas;
```

Decode the string into an array:

```
echo "Data with Json Decoding";
$decoded_datas = json_decode($encoded_datas, true);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($decoded_datas);
echo '</pre>';
```

You don't need to encode (and then decode) your array row by row.
Plus, as explained in comments and as shown in **costa**'s answer, your code didn't work because you were decoding the same string each time: your `$encoded` variable contains the last value you put in it (the last row you encoded).